# PowerPivot Pivot Table displays all rows instead of context rows

Tags: powerpivot

I'm looking for guidance on what changes need to be made to the model to get this pivot to display the proper rows under their respective jusridictions.
Currently the pivot displays ALL tax detail rows for each jusridiction.

Image 1 was removed due to posting limits.

Image 2 is the pivot after adding in the tax type.

[image]

Image 3 is the data model, showing the relation between the invoice data and the tax data. There can be 1 to many tax rows per invoice row.

[image]

If this question has been asked and answered before please provide a link. I don't have the time to scan 1000+ posts on PowerPivot to see if they apply. I did go through 150 of them with no joy.

Comment: Thanks @Juan, for your edit. Unfortunately you mixed up the images.

Comment: Issue resolved. Need to bring detail over to the tax details via sumx(relatedtable())